# Count objects within dynamic anonymous object (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, anonymous-types, dynamicobject

I have a dynamic object (it's actually json) that I pass into my MVC WebApi controller.

The json object contains multiple lists within an anonymous object that are submitted to the controller from another application via `client.PostAsJsonAsync("myapiurl", objectGraph)`.

What I need to do to validate the object on the MVC side, is to get the count of objects in each list. I can access the lists dynamically via `mydynamicobject.mylist` and individual items via `mydynamicobject.mylist[index]` but I can't seem to be able to get a count of `mydynamicobject.mylist`.

What I've tried so far:

- LINQ extension methods - doesn't work on dynamic
- `Enumerable.Count(mydynamicobject.mylist)` - can't infer type

Any other ideas? The count is actually correctly available in the dynamic object's `base` but obviously not accessible as a property. Help!

This works now:

```
// This is a MVC/WebApi method
public dynamic Post(dynamic mydynamicobject)

if (((ICollection)mydynamicobject.mylist).Count == 0)
{
// do something
}
```

The code that sends the dynamic object (different app):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add
  (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

var objectGraph = new { mylist = new { Id = 1 }, mylist2 = new { Name = "ABC" } }; 
var r = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/mycontroller", objectGraph).Result;
```

Comment: At what point does `mydynamicobject.mylist` fail - compile-time or execution time?

Comment: I only can't get to the count of the list within the dynamic object. The failure depends on what I try. Enumerable.Count will say that it can't infer the type and to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with `Enumerable.Count` - is the error at execution time, or compile time? What *is* the execution-time type of `mydynamicobject.mylist`?

Comment: That's at execution time. Not sure what the type would be considering that the object is dynamic. At creation time it's a simple list in an anonymous type (e.g. new x { new a { a1 = 1 }, new b { b1 = 1 } }).

Comment: That code wouldn't compile - if you could produce a short but *complete* example, it would make it much easier to make sure we gave you something that worked.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looking forward to your clarification as to why it works this way in a minute.  (At the moment in a Ruby/Javascript project at work, so i'm out of C# practice)

Comment: @Alex: `mylist` isn't a list herre - it's just an object with a single `Id` property. I'm surprised that works at all, in terms of casting it to `ICollection`...

Comment: Indeed, are you sure that this is the JSON you are posting? Because it shouldn't work at all, since `mylist` is not a list. Also, can you try to remove the cast to `ICollection` and check if `mydynamicobject.mylist.Count == 0` works for you? The cast seems to be redundant in this case.

Comment: Yes, that should be JSON. The `mydynamicobject.mylist.Count` doesn't work (it returns null). You are right in that my test program above wasn't actually a list; I've changed that and made it a real list. The ICollection code works as before.

Comment: Looks like this now: `var objectGraph = new { mylist = new { mylistobject1= new { Id = 1 }, mylistobject2 = new { Id = 2 } }, (...)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they are arrays, I believe you're looking for their `Length` property.

```
mydynamicobject.mylist.Length
```

Alternatively, I think you might be able to get away with casting `mydynamicobject.mylist` to an `IEnumerable` and then hand it to `IEnueramble.Count` like so:

```
IEnumerable.Count((IEnumerable)mydynamicobject.mylist);
```

you could *also* do as Paolo mentioned:

```
((ICollection)mydynamicobject.mylist).Count
```

Although I can't take credit for that one.

Comment: You mean `ICollection.Count`

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough. You can either try to cast it to `ICollection` and then check for [`ICollection.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.count.aspx), or cast it to `IEnumerable` and use the LINQ extension method [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx)

Comment: I was able to cast it to ICollection. Seems a little ugly-ish code, but at least it works. Thank you!

Comment: @JonSkeet would far more "ept" at explaining why the compiler and dynamic behaves this way.  I'd have to go dig out my copy of C# in Depth...and that would almost be like stealing Jon's answer.